I am building a back-end using Express.js and mongo (mongoose) and hosted in mongo atlas
When I run the command npm start I got this problem logged in the console:

(node:17724) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL
mongodb://chafik:@ac-i0d1tt9-shard-00-00.t8t0l7l.mongodb.net:27017,ac-i0d1tt9-shard-00-01.t8t0l7l.mongodb.net:27017,ac-i0d1tt9-shard-00-02.t8t0l7l.mongodb.net:27017/natours?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-11p2cm-shard-0&retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0&ssl=true
is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error

but the app still run and I don't have any problems requesting data or something like this, but still the problem keeps annoying me. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
N.B: In the application I changed <password> with the real password.
I tried to use the local database but they say it's good to hosted rather than using the local one, so I don't know what I should do.

You need to use at least v4 of the MongoDB driver - see e.g. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-5802?jql=text%20~%20%22DEP0170%22
